# PLS-00049: bad bind variable

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to write a trigger but I'm getting this error:

```
Error(44,3): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.NEW_REGION_CODE'
Error(45,5): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.NEW_REGION_DESC'
Error(46,5): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.NEW_MYHR_REGION_BI_CODE'
Error(47,3): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.NEW_MEDBEN_NUMOF_OPTIONS'
Error(48,5): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.NEW_DENTALBEN_NUMOF_OPTIONS'
Error(49,3): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.NEW_NUMOFHRS_WORKD_60PRORATION'
Error(50,5): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.NEW_NUMOFHRS_WORKD_80PRORATION'
Error(51,5): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.NEW_CREATED_BY'
Error(52,3): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.NEW_CREATED_ON'
```

Here is my trigger code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TRIGGER TRG_UPDT_REGION
BEFORE UPDATE ON REGION 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO REGION_HST 
( 
REGION_CODE, 
REGION_DESC, 
MYHR_REGION_BI_CODE, 
MEDBEN_NUMOF_OPTIONS, 
    DENTALBEN_NUMOF_OPTIONS, 
NUMOFHRS_WORKED_60PRORATION,
NUMOFHRS_WORKED_80PRORATION,
CREATED_BY,
CREATED_ON, 
UPDATED_BY, 
UPDATED_ON,
DELETED_BY,
DELETED_ON, 
    NEW_REGION_CODE,
NEW_REGION_DESC, 
NEW_MYHR_REGION_BI_CODE, 
NEW_MEDBEN_NUMOF_OPTIONS, 
NEW_DENTALBEN_NUMOF_OPTIONS, 
    NEW_NUMOFHRS_WORKD_60PRORATION,
NEW_NUMOFHRS_WORKD_80PRORATION, 
NEW_CREATED_BY, 
NEW_CREATED_ON, 
NEW_UPDATED_BY, 
NEW_UPDATED_ON
)
    VALUES 
    ( 
:OLD.REGION_CODE, 
:OLD.REGION_DESC, 
:OLD.MYHR_REGION_BI_CODE, 
    :OLD.MEDBEN_NUMOF_OPTIONS,
:OLD.DENTALBEN_NUMOF_OPTIONS,
:OLD.NUMOFHRS_WORKED_60PRORATION, 
    :OLD.NUMOFHRS_WORKED_80PRORATION, 
:OLD.CREATED_BY,
:OLD.CREATED_ON,
:OLD.UPDATED_BY, 
    :OLD.UPDATED_ON,
APEX_APPLICATION.G_USER,
SYSDATE, 
    :NEW.NEW_REGION_CODE,
:NEW.NEW_REGION_DESC, 
:NEW.NEW_MYHR_REGION_BI_CODE, 
    :NEW.NEW_MEDBEN_NUMOF_OPTIONS, 
:NEW.NEW_DENTALBEN_NUMOF_OPTIONS, 
    :NEW.NEW_NUMOFHRS_WORKD_60PRORATION, 
:NEW.NEW_NUMOFHRS_WORKD_80PRORATION, 
:NEW.NEW_CREATED_BY, 
    :NEW.NEW_CREATED_ON, 
APEX_APPLICATION.G_USER,
SYSDATE);
END;
```

I've searched for questions with the same issue but none of them have solved my problem. I've also checked for spelling mistakes and I'm sure that the spelling is correct.

Comment: Please show the defintion for the table `REGION` (e.g. as a `create table` statement)

Comment: Can you add the structure of your `REGION` table to the question? Does it really have columns like `NEW_REGION_CODE`, or have you just added an extra `NEW_` in there by mistake?

Comment: you're sure columns `NEW_REGION_CODE`, and the other ones starting with `NEW_` exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means the `:NEW` pseudorecord doesn't have fields with the names you've used, which means the table the trigger is against doesn't have columns with those names.

Based on the `:OLD` values you are using, you've just introduced spurious `NEW_` prefixes to your column names; so the values clause should be:

```
VALUES 
( 
    :OLD.REGION_CODE, 
    ...
    :OLD.UPDATED_ON,
    APEX_APPLICATION.G_USER,
    SYSDATE, 
    :NEW.REGION_CODE,
    :NEW.REGION_DESC, 
    :NEW.MYHR_REGION_BI_CODE, 
    :NEW.MEDBEN_NUMOF_OPTIONS, 
    :NEW.DENTALBEN_NUMOF_OPTIONS, 
    :NEW.NUMOFHRS_WORKD_60PRORATION, 
    :NEW.NUMOFHRS_WORKD_80PRORATION, 
    :NEW.CREATED_BY, 
    :NEW.CREATED_ON, 
    APEX_APPLICATION.G_USER,
    SYSDATE
);
```